# How to tune the spark application in order to avoid OOM exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I use Spark 2.0.2.

I am trying to run a spark application that does prediction on an already created model.

Cluster Info: m4.2xlarge 16 vCPU, 32 GiB memory, EBS only storage EBS Storage:1000 GiB

Based on the recommendations made [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/) I have made a [Google-Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_bOmD3VxX6fKT1yM_wsU_cdgLD_HYtXzRRxOlPuxMvc/edit?usp=sharing) to compute the tuning parameters.

No matter what I try I am getting the following 2 exceptions:

1. Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 10.0 GB of 10 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
2. Executor heartbeat timed out after 159126 ms

Below is the code that I am trying to execute

```
val allGears = sc.textFile(allGearsFilePath)
val allUsers = sc.textFile(allUsersFilePath)
val allUserItems = allUsers.cartesian(allGears).map{ case(x,y) => (x.toInt, y.toInt)}
allUserItems.cache()


val gearPurchased = sc.textFile(gearPurchaseRating)
val gearAddedToCart = sc.textFile(gearAddToCartRating)
val gearShoppingUserToItem = gearPurchased.map(_.split(',') match   { case Array(user, item, rate) => (user.toInt, item.toInt) })
gearShoppingUserToItem.cache()
val allUserItemToGearShoppingUnion = allUserItems.union(gearShoppingUserToItem)
val allUserItemToGearShoppingIntersection = allUserItems.intersection(gearShoppingUserToItem)
val FinalSubtraction = allUserItems.subtract(gearShoppingUserToItem)
val nonPurchasedGears = FinalSubtraction
nonPurchasedGears.cache()
allUserItems.unpersist()
gearShoppingUserToItem.unpersist()
val out = model.predict(nonPurchasedGears)
```

I get the exception when I try to Predict what gears can be purchased by the users.

Below is the spark-submit command that I run

```
spark-submit --jars jedis-2.7.2.jar,commons-pool2-2.3.jar,spark-redis-0.3.2.jar,SparkHBase.jar,recommendcontentslib_2.11-1.0.jar --class org.digitaljuice.itemrecommender.RecommendGears --master yarn --driver-memory 2g --num-executors 5 --executor-memory 9g --executor-cores 5 --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024 recommendersystem_2.11-0.0.1.jar /work/output/gearpurchaserating/part-00000 /work/output/gearaddtocartrating/part-00000 /work/output/allGears/part-00000 /work/output/allAccounts/part-00000 /work/allaccounts/acc_toacc/part-m-00000 /work/Recommendations/ /work/TrainingModel
```

How can I tune the application so that it runs and makes the prediction?
I have tried various things, but nothing seems to work, so I am guessing I am not tuning the application right. Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you change `allUserItems.cache()` to `allUserItems.cache().count()` to trigger the caching right on the line? Same for `gearShoppingUserToItem.cache()`. That will give you some idea what/when fails. Besides, why do you use RDD API? It's 21st century already :)

Comment: I see you have several `cache` calls and since `cache` persists _only_ to memory you can quickly run into problems with OOMs. Which stage in your DAG is being evaluated when you see the error?

Comment: Oh yes, and which version of Spark are you running?

Comment: I'm saying that they are a likely pitfall (generally, I would recommend `.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)` unless you are absolutely sure data will fit in memory). You are however also doing other things could case OOMs, which is why I asked in which stage you see the error.

Comment: Just when I try to predict, on this line
val out = model.predict(nonPurchasedGears)

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: What do you recommend to use instead of RDD?

Comment: @Adit The latest APIs of Spark SQL and Spark MLlib, i.e. DataFrame API and Pipeline API, respectively. A few performance problems might never surface if you rely on the native query planning and optimizations.

Comment: The line `out = model.predict(nonPurchasedGears)` is just what triggers evaluation. You need to look into which of the preceeding stages is actually causing the problem

Comment: I think you are using cache wrong. You should assign the cached rdd to a new val and use that: val cachedRdd = rdd.cache. Not sure this is the reason for the failure, but definitely something in need of fixing.

Comment: Also, sometimes the error says it all: try boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead a bit more than the default.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt I did perform the count() on each of RDD's created and none of those triggered the OOM exception, but while trying to execute this line of code it throws the exception:
`val FinalSubtraction = allUserItems.subtract(gearShoppingUserToItem)`
I think the subtract operation between the sets is causing the exception. What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so rather than continuing in the comment track I will jump right into a purposed solution, which also entails a little clean up of your code.

```
val allGears = spark.read.csv(allGearsFilePath)
val allUsers = spark.read.csv(allUsersFilePath)
val allUserItems = allUsers.crossJoin(allGears).map{case Row(x: String,y: String) => (x.toInt, y.toInt)}.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

val gearPurchased = spark.read.csv(gearPurchaseRating)

val gearShoppingUserToItem = gearPurchased.map{case Row(x: String,y: String) => (x.toInt, y.toInt)}.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
val nonPurchasedGears = allUserItems.except(gearShoppingUserToItem).cache()

val gearAddedToCart = spark.read.csv(gearAddToCartRating) // NOT USED
val allUserItemToGearShoppingUnion = allUserItems.union(gearShoppingUserToItem) // NOT USED
val allUserItemToGearShoppingIntersection = allUserItems.intersect(gearShoppingUserToItem) // NOT USED

allUserItems.unpersist()
gearShoppingUserToItem.unpersist()

val out = model.predict(nonPurchasedGears)
```

There are a number of variables that are not used in you example - I have left them there in case you need them for later on. If you do *not* need them, remove them. (Also, if you remove them, there is no reason to cache any of the dataframes and you could simply remove all `persist` and `cache` from the code as well.)

Anyway, back to the issue - if you still run into an OOM, you could try a number of things:

- Increase `memoryOverhead`. In Spark 2.x there is an increased usage of off heap memory and you generally need to increase memoryOverhead. Try increasing it to 4096 (note that you may need to lower `--executor-memory` so you don't exceed available memory).
- Repartition your data into more partitions before doing `except`
- Force evaluation and caching of your persisted dataframes by adding `allUserItems.count` and `gearShoppingUserToItem.count` before calling `except`. I know this sound odd, but it will frequently solve OOM problems and also speed up your code significantly.

I hope this helps :)